# Stop form submit depending on ajax response

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I am using onsubmit="return check_for_conflict()" to call this function:

```
function check_for_conflict(){
var client_id = $('#agent_select').val();

//Stop submit if no agent selected.
if (client_id == 0){
    alert("Please select an agent.")
    return false;
}
var duration = $('#select_job_duration').val();
var id = $('#input_id').val();
var dat = $('#input_date').val();
var st_time = $('#input_st_time').val();

//Check if scheduling conflict and stop submit if there is a conflict.
$.post("check_for_conflicts.php", { job_duration: duration, provider_id: id, job_date: dat, job_st_time: st_time },
    function(data){
        console.log(data.status);
        if(data.status == 'conflict'){
            alert("There is a conflict with this time.")
            return false;
        }
    }, "json"
);

//Continue submit if now scheduled conflicts.
return true;
```

}

I have two checks to stop the form to submit.  The second check depends on the .post response.  This part is not working because it hit the final "return true" before the .post is done.  How do I use the .post response to stop the form from being submitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can (but not like that), just always prevent the form from submitting, then submit it in the ajax success handler with the native submit:

remove the inline JS:

```
<form id="someform">
    <!-- form content -->
</form>
```

and then do :

```
$('#someform').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form      = this,
        client_id = $('#agent_select').val();

    if (client_id == 0) {
        alert("Please select an agent.");
    }else{
        var data = {
            job_duration : $('#select_job_duration').val(),
            provider_id  : $('#input_id').val(),
            job_date     : $('#input_date').val(),
            job_st_time  : $('#input_st_time').val()
        };

        $.post("check_for_conflicts.php", data, function(result){
            console.log(result.status);
            if( $.trim( result.status ) == 'conflict') {
                alert("There is a conflict with this time.")
            }else{
                form.submit();
            }
        }, "json");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I use the .post response to stop the form from being submitted?

You can't. As observed, and specified, it's asynchronous.

You will need to prevent the post at any rate, and do a programmatic submit on your success function of the AJAX call. Perhaps setting a variable beforehand to distinguish the first submit from the re-submit.